# Структура виртуальной памяти процесса в Linux

Tags: linux, c, x86-64, x86, виртуальная-память

Как распределены и по каким регистрам процессора указатели, задающие границы области стека, области динамических данных, области статических данных и области команд модуля программы?

Comment: Стоит различать модель памяти языка и организацию памяти непосредственно на целевой машине. Вопрос из заголовка и вопрос в тексте - разные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос почти не связан с языком C или компилятором GCC, а связан больше с операционной системой, в которой выполняется программа. Конкретно, вас интересует *карта виртуальной памяти процесса* — именно она определяет, где по каким адресам расположен стек, куча и сегменты исполняемого файла (те самые `.bss`, `.text`, `.data` и прч.). Ниже приведен ответ для ОС с ядром Linux и архитектурой семейства x86.

---

Ядро Linux делит всё виртуальное адресное пространства процесса на две части: *user-space memory* и *kernel memory*. Конкретное деление различно, есть как минимум три варианта:

1. В архитектуре i386 *обычно* все виртуальное адресное пространство имеет размер 4 GiB и ядро выделяет нижние 3 GiB для user-space и верхний 1 GiB для самого ядра<sup>*</sup>.
2. В архитектуре x86_64 с 4-х уровневыми page tables виртуальное адресное пространство является 48-битным. User-space memory занимает 128 TB, начиная с адреса `0x0000000000000000` и заканчивая адресом `0x00007fffffffffff`. Kernel memory также занимает 128 TB, начиная с адреса `0xffff800000000000` и заканчивая адресом `0xffffffffffffffff` <sup>†</sup>.
3. В архитектуре x86_64 с 5-ти уровневыми page tables виртуальное адресное пространство является 56-битным, а схема его разбиения похожа на (2) <sup>†</sup>.

Память ядра является одинаковой и разделяемой для всех программ, поэтому нас будет интересовать user-space memory.

Как ни странно, но найти конкретную информацию по разбиению адресного пространства процесса в Linux не так просто. Мне удалось найти достаточно подробную статью *[“Understanding the Memory Layout of Linux Executables”](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/10ab53654b2aa6ce55c11cfc5b2432a4)*, где после довольно долго расследования выясняется примерно следующее распределение памяти процесса:

> ```
> 0
> Nothing here, because it was just an arbitrary choice by the linker
> ELF and Program and Section Headers - 0x400000 on 64 bit
> Program Text (.text) - Entry Point as Reported by readelf
> Nothing Here either
> Some unknown assembly and data - 0x600000
> Initialised Data (.data) - 0x601068
> Uninitialised Data (.bss) - 0x601078
> Heap
>     |
>     v
> Memory Mapped Region for Shared Libraries or Anything Else
>     ^
>     |
> User Stack
> ```

Таким образом видим, что *стек* (англ. *stack*) располагается в самом конце адресного пространства и расет «вниз»<sup>‡</sup>, то есть по направлению к младшим адресам (к нулю). В свою очередь, *куча* (англ. *heap*) растет «вверх» и располагается сразу после секции `.bss`.

По-умолчанию размер стека равен 8 MiB. Изначально под стек выделяется его первая страница памяти 4 KiB. Если пользовательский код выходит за пределы этих 4 KiB, то происходит Page Fault, которое ловит ядро. Затем ядро проверяет, не вышел ли стек за границу в 8 MiB. Если не вышел — выделяет новую странцу для стека (стек растет), если  вышел — убивает процесс.

Размер стека можно менять из пространства пользователя с помощью программы `ulimit`.

Также стоит отметить, что конкретные адреса кучи и стека всегда будут разными при каждом запуске из-за [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (Address Space Layer Randomization). Функции для их рандомизации находятся в файле [`linux/mm/util.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d0a231f01e5b25bacd23e6edc7c979a18a517b2b/mm/util.c). Конкретно это функции [`randomize_stack_top`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d0a231f01e5b25bacd23e6edc7c979a18a517b2b/mm/util.c#L330) и [`arch_randomize_brk`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d0a231f01e5b25bacd23e6edc7c979a18a517b2b/mm/util.c#L347).

#### Практический способ выяснения структуры памяти процесса

Другим способом выяснить разметку памяти процесса в Linux будет использование файла `/proc/<PID>/maps`, который собственно и содержит информацию об адресном пространстве процесса. Если написать простейший hello world, можно увидеть примерно следующее:

```
$ cat /proc/$(pidof hello)/maps
558c1ca6f000-558c1ca70000 r--p 00000000 00:20 638                        /tmp/hello
558c1ca70000-558c1ca71000 r-xp 00001000 00:20 638                        /tmp/hello
558c1ca71000-558c1ca72000 r--p 00002000 00:20 638                        /tmp/hello
558c1ca72000-558c1ca73000 r--p 00002000 00:20 638                        /tmp/hello
558c1ca73000-558c1ca74000 rw-p 00003000 00:20 638                        /tmp/hello
558c1e82c000-558c1e84d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ff9a4a01000-7ff9a4a03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff9a4a03000-7ff9a4a29000 r--p 00000000 103:04 789879                    /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so
7ff9a4a29000-7ff9a4b74000 r-xp 00026000 103:04 789879                    /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so
7ff9a4b74000-7ff9a4bc0000 r--p 00171000 103:04 789879                    /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so
7ff9a4bc0000-7ff9a4bc3000 r--p 001bc000 103:04 789879                    /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so
7ff9a4bc3000-7ff9a4bc6000 rw-p 001bf000 103:04 789879                    /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so
7ff9a4bc6000-7ff9a4bd1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff9a4be3000-7ff9a4be4000 r--p 00000000 103:04 789868                    /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so
7ff9a4be4000-7ff9a4c08000 r-xp 00001000 103:04 789868                    /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so
7ff9a4c08000-7ff9a4c11000 r--p 00025000 103:04 789868                    /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so
7ff9a4c11000-7ff9a4c13000 r--p 0002d000 103:04 789868                    /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so
7ff9a4c13000-7ff9a4c15000 rw-p 0002f000 103:04 789868                    /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so
7ffecbeaf000-7ffecbed0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffecbf31000-7ffecbf35000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffecbf35000-7ffecbf37000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Здесь видно, что первые пять строк файла означают секции исполняемого файла `/tmp/hello`. Конкретные названия не указаны, но о значении некоторых секций можно догадаться по выставленным *разрешениям* (англ. *permissions*).

Так же можно использовать программу-фронтенд `pmap`:

```
$ pmap $(pidof hello)
35111:   ./hello
000055eef0906000      4K r---- hello
000055eef0907000      4K r-x-- hello
000055eef0908000      4K r---- hello
000055eef0909000      4K r---- hello
000055eef090a000      4K rw--- hello
000055eef116b000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2b7a11f000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2b7a121000    152K r---- libc-2.33.so
00007f2b7a147000   1324K r-x-- libc-2.33.so
00007f2b7a292000    304K r---- libc-2.33.so
00007f2b7a2de000     12K r---- libc-2.33.so
00007f2b7a2e1000     12K rw--- libc-2.33.so
00007f2b7a2e4000     44K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2b7a301000      4K r---- ld-2.33.so
00007f2b7a302000    144K r-x-- ld-2.33.so
00007f2b7a326000     36K r---- ld-2.33.so
00007f2b7a32f000      8K r---- ld-2.33.so
00007f2b7a331000      8K rw--- ld-2.33.so
00007ffd6e1a9000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffd6e1cb000     16K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffd6e1cf000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K --x--   [ anon ]
 total             2368K
```

---

<sup>* В [комментарии](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509607/how-a-64-bit-process-virtual-address-space-is-divided-in-linux#comment1260810_509607) под одним из вопросов на Unix SE пользователь с ником @phuclv утверждает, что это не совсем верная информация. Согласно комментарию, «*в зависимости от версии ядра отношение разбиения может отличаться. Старые версии могут использовать разбиения 1/3, 2/2 или 3/1, что указывается опциями `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_`; а с 2007 года можно выбрать дробные разбиения типа 5/16-тых и 15/32-ых. Если в ручную поменять некоторые `#define`-ы, можно добиться произвольных разбиений. Сегодня системы, подверженные уязвимости Meltdown обычно используют разбиение 4/4, то есть полностью отдельные адресные пространства для ядра и пользовательского режима*».</sup>

<sup>† Детальное описание карты виртуальной памяти для x86_64 можно найти в [документации](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) к ядру.</sup>

<sup>‡ Направление роста стека на самом деле платформо-зависимо. См. соответствующий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1677415/8086115) на enSO.</sup>